# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Cmd+Left/Right in UItextView

Tags: ios, crash, uitextview, bluetooth-keyboard

Steps to Crash:

- сreate "simple view application".
- Add textView and set some for it properties(you can see it in code bellow).
- Cursor should be between points in the center of the field.(you should add a long string to see points in the center)
- Connect bluetooth keyboard
  to device.
- Move cursor to the center of the field
- Press Cmd+Left/Right
- Always crash

It is all code which I rote:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1;
    self.textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
}

@end
```

Crash info:
Nothing in logs, just:
in UITextView error: memory read failed for 0x0

I can't find anything about this problem on stackoverflow or in the internet. Does anyone has a any ideas about it? Or just report to apple?

Tested on:

- iPad 4 iOS 8.3(12F69)
- iPad mini 9 betta 3(13A4293g)

[image: coursor should be between points in the center of the field]

Comment: It's already fixed by apple.